# Is there an easy way to get in-line expanded JSON format from Contentful response

Tags: json, rest, content-management-system, contentful

Contentful is a very useful service but unfortunately the json response format does not allow for standard expanded json data format.

It requires us to write and extra translator to return common json structure nesting.

For instance, with Contentful we get (simplified version)

```
{
"module" : {
      "lessons" : [
          "id": "<lesson_id>"
      ]
    }

  "includes": {
    "Entry": [
      {
        id: "<lesson_id>",
        lesson : {
            "lesson data" : "lesson data",
            topics : [
                "id" : "<topic_id>"
            ]
        }
      },
        id: "<topic_id>",
        topic : {
            "topic data" : "topic data",
            ]
        }    
      }
    ]
  }
```

But we want this

```
{
"module" : {
      "lessons" : [ 
          {
                "lessonData" : "lesson data",
                "topics" : [
                    {
                      "topicData" : "topic data",
                    }
                ]
          }
      ],
    }
}
```

Anyone have a generalized tool to assemble a Contentful response into a standard json response?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any of our SDKs? They have Include resolution built-in so that you don't have to do this manually.

There are many tools built already with them to, for example, serialize content to YAML (using a format similar to what you describe) so that static site generators can consume from it.

You can read more about this on our developers page: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/

Hope this helps

Comment: We'd prefer to use the standard REST api.  Is there a reason that Contentful doesnt have an option to output this standard json format?
Is there a specific tool in the dev section that can generate the standard json I mentioned?

Comment: The reason for related entries being in the includes section is to reduce clutter and increase response speed. This is mostly because entries and assets can be linked in many other resources, therefore generating ever-increasing responses. This way we keep it clean and simple.